# using EndsWith() inside List.Any() is not working as expected

Tags: c#

I have the following code inside my c# console application, where i want to check if a string `cleanedphone` end with any entry inside a list of strings:-

```
static List<string> Mylist;
var cleanedphone = new string(phone.Trim().Replace(" ", "").Where(c => char.IsDigit(c)).ToArray());//remove non numeric chars + white spaces
si.status = Mylist.Any(a => cleanedphone.EndsWith(a)) ? "Yes" : "No";
```

but in my case the .Any() will return `Yes` even if the `cleanedphone` does not end with any entry inside the `Mylist`... so can anyone advice ?
Thanks

Comment: Post example data and expected output. The methods work well. If you get unexpected results it's probably because eg `cleanedphone` isn't what you expected, or the static `Mylist` contains unexpected data from a previous execution. *Don't* use static fields to pass data around, use method parameters or, in the worst case, instance fields

Comment: BTW a simple regex would be faster *and* produce no temporary strings

Comment: Try trim : cleanedphone.Trim().EndsWith(a)

Comment: No repro by the way. If I use `"+123-1235"` as `phone` and `var Mylist=new List<string> { "1235"};` as a list, I get `Yes`

Comment: `Regex.Replace("+123-1235","\\D","")` will remove any non-digit information from the string by the way, eg `var cleanedPhone=Regex.Replace("+123-1235","\\D","")`. A Regex is thread-safe and reusable, which means *it* can be created once and stored in a static field and reused, eg `Regex cleanUp=new Regex("\\D"); ..... var cleanedPhone=cleanup.Replace(phone,"");`

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos thanks for the reply , i provided a sample of the list...

Comment: @jdweng i already trimmed the `cleanedphone` when i build the string...

Comment: @testtest is this an empty line or empty string?

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos i am building the list from a text file,, so this is an empty line inside the text file, which will be represented as an entry with empty value inside the list..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is cause by the empty string in the list. String.EndsWith returns `true` for every string if the input is an empty string, eg :

```
"abc".EndsWith("");
```

Returns true.

You'll have to clean up the list of suffixes, eg with :

```
myList=myList.Where(x=>!String.IsNullOrWhitespace(x)).ToList();
```

You can speed up and simplify your code if you use a regular expression stored in a static field to remove non-numeric characters, eg :

```
static Regex _cleanup;
static List<string> _suffixes;

static void Initialize(string sourcePath)
{
    _cleanup  = new Regex("\\D");
    _suffixes = File.ReadLines(sourcePath)
                    .Where(x=>!String.IsNullOrWhitespace(x))
                    .ToList();
}

public string CheckPhone(string phone)
{
    var cleanedphone = _cleanup.Replace(phone,"");
    var result = _suffixes.Any(a => cleanedphone.EndsWith(a)) ? "Yes" : "No";
    return result;
}


`File.ReadLines` returns an `IEnumerable<string>` instead of `string[]` which means you don't have to load the entire file before cleaning up the entries
```

Answer (score 4):

The issue with your code is that your List contains an Empty String. An easier way forward would be to remove the empty string.

```
var status = Mylist.Where(a=>a.Length>0).Any(a => cleanedphone.EndsWith(a)) ? "Yes" : "No";
```

Or combining the conditions

```
var status = Mylist.Any(a => a.Length>0 && cleanedphone.EndsWith(a)) ? "Yes" : "No";
```

As a footnote, it would be better if you could use Regex for cleaning up the phone number for non-numeric characters. For example,

```
var cleanedphone = Regex.Replace(phone, @"\D", string.Empty);
```

Answer (score 1):

This works for me:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
            string input = @"58181
09905352823
09912713815
09913842311
09915345235
09921174632
0992578810 
0992711803 
0995640639 
09965262212
09971159292
0997626372 
09988772816
09999100244

01132171481
01132672788
01133804928
01142692085
01142880116
01142962865
0114457953
01787227855
01788438359
01788536032
01788561185
01788574002
01788878949
01789721106
07594135168
07594189551
07594538828
07594791499
01912372953
01912375775
01912376383
01912415145
01912434658
01912502728
07989244376
07989384524
07989491312
07989549434";

        List<string> numbers = input.Split(new string[] { Environment.NewLine }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries).ToList();

        string cleanedPhone = "992043411000";

        string status = numbers.Any(x => cleanedPhone.EndsWith(x)) ? "Yes" : "No";

        Console.WriteLine(status);
    }
}
```

Comment: thanks for the reply this worked for me.... But can i ask you to remove the numbers from your reply as they represents some live date for us.. thanks

Comment: @testtest you shouldn't have posted them in the question then. Post an example that actually reproduces the problem with *dummy* data. WIthout that list the question doesn't make sense

Comment: @Marco Salerno yes i agree with you, i thought i would remove them later on, and since the problem was with the white space.. anyway i would appreciate it if you edit your answer and remove the list of numbers.. thanks